# How do I solve "Instance method [...] not found" errors?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, selector

I'm developing a Cocoa application. As far as I can tell, I am doing everything correctly when trying to call a method in a selector.  For example (abstracted):

**Header.h**

```
@interface Foo

@property (nonatomic) BOOL variable;

- (void)bar;

@end
```

**Header.m**

```
#import "Header.h"

@implementation Foo

@synthesize variable;

- (void)bar
{
    NSLog("Test");
}

@end
```

**OtherHeader.m**

```
#import "Header.h"

@implementation OtherFoo

- (IBAction)otherBar:(id)sender
{
    Foo *foo = [sender representedObject];
    [foo bar]; // Generates warning
    BOOL variable = [foo variable]; // No warning
}

@end
```

When I do this, the expression `[foo bar]` gets the warning "Instance method "-bar" not found (return type defaults to 'id').

I realize that similar questions have been asked a lot on SO, but I've looked through these (and the documentation for cocoa and selectors) extensively, and nothing has helped.  The most common causes of this error seem to be leaving out the implementation of `bar` or the reference to **Header.h**, but as you can see, I have both.

**EDIT**: The selector is called from an instance of `NSMenuItem` - that's why I'm calling `representedObject`.

**EDIT 2**: For some reason, other instance methods and properties don't generate the warning. Just specific instance methods. So weird.

Comment: What happens if you do: `Foo *foo = (Foo *)[sender representedObject];`?

Comment: The same thing happens using a C-style cast, unfortunately. Good idea, though.

Comment: Why are you calling `representedObject`?  And where is documentation for this method...?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have mentioned that the selector is called from an instance of [NSMenuItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsmenuitem_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMenuItem/representedObject)

Comment: What if you changed the method to `- (IBAction)otherBar:(NSMenuItem *)sender` ?

Comment: I'm guessing that there is some subtle typo somewhere that is causing the header file to not be read or some such.  These can be hard to find, but the best approach is generally to get a second example that does work, then slowly modify it to match the non-functioning case.  Usually you'll find some modification makes the difference, and from that you can find your bug.

Comment: Is it possible that `bar` is internal somehow? I didn't say this in the problem statement, but in my specific case, the two header files are in different projects...

Comment: It doesn't matter where the header files are as long as you're able to import them.  They're either part of the project or they're not.

Comment: @nhgrif that's what I thought...back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. I'm an idiot. This problem was caused by me not building it. Since `OtherHeader.h` was in a separate project, the XCode auto complete couldn't see it in the library file until that project was compiled.

So from this and my previous internet research, I'll sum up what I know the causes of this error to be:

1. Missing header file for the class containing the instance method
2. Missing implementation of the instance method
3. Project containing the header with the instance method has not been built since the instance method was added. This situation also may only arise if you are sending the message to invoke the instance method from a separate project.

I hope this helps anyone who, like myself, has spent hours staring in bewilderment at this error.